# Will unspecified keys and sub-entries be kept unchanged when double click reg file?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Suppose there is a `.reg` file that specifies a registry entry with partial keys and values. This registry entry actually has much more keys, values and sub-entries stored in behind as shown in RegEdit.exe.

When I double click this `.reg` file, will the unspecified keys and sub-entries (and their keys and values) be deleted? Or just kept unchanged?

Is there any website that explicitly states that unspecified ones will be kept unchanged?

Comment: kept unchanged.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for reply. Is there any supporting website talking about this? I search for a while and ask Bing chat but did not find any website that explicitly state that unspecified ones will be kept unchanged .....

Comment: try it - obviously not with anything important, create your own key, maybe in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\DummySoftware` or some such - I did try before saying "kept unchanged" - as for documentation for it ... MicroSoft + Documentation = Hit and Miss

Answer (score 0):

A `.reg` file only adds items. For such a file to delete items requires
special syntax:

- To delete a value requires a hyphen after the equals sign :
  `"TestValue"=-`
- To delete a registry key with all its subkeys,
  put a hyphen (-) in front of the key:
  `[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test]`

Reference :
[How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg-file-9c7f37cf-a5e9-e1cd-c4fa-2a26218a1a23).